# optimise efficiency in display mysql query results in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a query that returns an entire table.
The only way I found to display the data as an HTML table is by creating an array for each column:

```
var date = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    date[i] = arr[i].nullinfoDate;
}
var number = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    number[i] = arr[i].nullinfoNumber;
}
var bool = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    bool[i] = arr[i].nullinfoBool;
}
var text1 = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    text1[i] = arr[i].nullinfoText1;
}
var text2 = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    text2[i] = arr[i].nullinfoText2;
}
```

and then sending all the columns to the HTML template:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'home',
        date: date,
        number: number,
        bool: bool,
        text1: text1,
        text2: text2
    });
});
```

But that feels extremely inefficient. Is there a better way to do that?

HTML (EJS) template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <table>

    <% for(var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= date[i] %></td>
        <td><%= number[i] %></td>
        <td><%= bool[i] %></td>
        <td><%= text1[i] %></td>
        <td><%= text2[i] %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show your HTML template?

Comment: Thanks! Could you also describe how exactly the data returned by your query (`arr`) look like?

Comment: `[ RowDataPacket {
    NULLINFOId: 7,
    nullinfoDate: Wed Aug 17 2016 13:48:18 GMT+0300 (IDT),
    nullinfoNumber: 877,
    nullinfoBool: 0,
    nullinfoText1: 'word',
    nullinfoText2: 'phrase' },
  RowDataPacket {
    NULLINFOId: 8,
    nullinfoDate: Wed Aug 17 2016 13:48:53 GMT+0300 (IDT),
    nullinfoNumber: 924,
    nullinfoBool: 1,
    nullinfoText1: 'something',
    nullinfoText2: 'stuff' },` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's enough to pass the data returned by your query directly:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'home',
        data: arr
    });
});
```

Then in your template, you can just do:

```
<table>

<% for (let datum of data) {%>
<tr>
    <td><%= datum.nullinfoDate %></td>
    <td><%= datum.nullinfoNumber %></td>
    <td><%= datum.nullinfoBool %></td>
    <td><%= datum.nullinfoText1 %></td>
    <td><%= datum.nullinfoText2 %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>

</table>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Only with var or const instead of let, but no matter

Comment: @user3187759 Cool :)